# Make fadeToggle more smooth when collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fade

When I click toggle the `Toggle` anchor in my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KAAHM/ when the animation is complete, the collapsing of the remaining `<li>` is jarring and abrupt.

I was wondering if there was a quick way to make it smooth like: http://razorjack.net/quicksand/?

How the remaining items slide to their new spots rather than just collapse.

Don't think I have to keep `fadeToggle` but I would like it to fade and then disappear visibly, then physically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/KAAHM/1/

Basic idea behind, is to apply width to parent `li` elements, fade out the anchors and then animate width of parent li elements down to zero, and finally remove those elements.

That way, the one element that stays put is smoothly placed near left edge of parent container.

Comment: I like it but how about when I click it again, I need the items to reappear. Like in the original it toggles.